# Find Method Object Variable Not Set

Tags: vba, excel

This is an error I've been trying to figure out for awhile now, my find method is not producing any results and I cannot figure out why.

The code is suppose to search InputSheet for a string, report the row number and start moving information over to Background based on that row number. Then the next .find will find the string in SummaryResults and start moving information from Background, reformat it a bit, and paste to SummaryResults.

My find method is not producing any results and leaves FindRow = Nothing even though the strings are present in the sheets and in the correct Ranges.

This error started occurring after running the macro with another Excel sheet open so maybe the ActiveWorkbook was incorrect, but I have not been able to get it to run since.

Some of the variables shown are from other sections of the code but when I hover over them in the debug mode they are showing what they're suppose to.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CAESARCONVERSION()
Dim InputSheet As Worksheet, SummaryResults As Worksheet, Background As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim h As Integer
Dim v As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim myBook As Workbook
Set myBook = Excel.ThisWorkbook
Set InputSheet = myBook.Sheets("Input Sheet")
Set SummaryResults = myBook.Sheets("Summary Results")
Set Background = myBook.Sheets("Background")
Dim NodeList As Integer
Dim TotalCases As Integer
Dim sMyString As String
Dim Nodes As Variant
Dim FindRow As Range
Dim intValueToFind As String
Dim FindRowNumber As Long
Dim SecondRowNumber As Long



'Clear the last run of macro
Background.Range("A2:A1000").Cells.Clear
Background.Range("C2:I10000").Cells.Clear
SummaryResults.Cells.Clear
'Code that will count the total number of load cases

TotalCases = 0
h = 2
Dim text As String
For v = 12 To 100
    If InputSheet.Cells(v, 2).Value <> "" Then
        text = LTrim(InputSheet.Cells(v, 2).Value)
        Background.Cells(h, 3).Value = text
        h = h + 1
        TotalCases = TotalCases + 1
    Else
        GoTo NodeCounter
    End If
Next v

NodeCounter:
y = TotalCases - 1
x = 0
    Dim LoadCaseList() As Variant
    ReDim LoadCaseList(y)

LoadCaseList:
For x = 0 To y
    LoadCaseList(x) = Background.Cells(2 + x, 3).text
Next x


j = 2

For i = 17 + TotalCases To 20000 'Need to define how far for the program to search, we may exceed 20000 at some point
    If InputSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
    Background.Cells(j, 1).Value = InputSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
    j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

With Background
NodeList = Background.Cells(2, 2).Value
Background.Range("AA1:XX" & NodeList + 1).Cells.Clear
End With

ReDim Nodes(NodeList - 1)
v = 0
j = 2
For i = 0 To NodeList - 1
    Nodes(i) = Background.Cells(j, 1).Value
    j = j + 1
Next i



Headers:
Dim LoadCaseHeader() As String
Dim TypHeader()
TypHeader = Array("Node", "L", "Direction", "Magnitude")
Dim LoadDirections()
LoadDirections = Array("X", "Y", "Z", "MX", "MY", "MZ")

x = 0
z = 0

For x = 0 To NodeList - 1
    For z = 0 To TotalCases - 1
        SummaryResults.Range(("B" & 2 + (NodeList * 6 + 2) * z) & ":" & "E" & 2 + (NodeList * 6 + 2) * z) = TypHeader()
        SummaryResults.Range("A" & 2 + (NodeList * 6 + 2) * z) = Background.Range("C" & 2 + z)
    Next z
Next x

'Search rows for the first instance of this value.



LoadCases:

'Code that copies information from the InputSheet to the SummaryResults
Dim LoadCases() As Long
ReDim LoadCases(NodeList, 6)
FindRowNumber = 0
SecondRowNumber = 0

For c = 0 To y

    intValueToFind = LoadCaseList(c)
    For i = 7 To 31 + TotalCases
        With InputSheet
            If Trim(Cells(i, 3).Value) = intValueToFind Then
                MsgBox ("Found")
                Set FindRow = InputSheet.Range("C:C").Find(What:=intValueToFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
                FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row
            End If
        End With
    Next i

    'MsgBox FindRowNumber

    With InputSheet
        For i = 0 To NodeList - 1
        x = 4
            For j = 0 To 5
                LoadCases(i, j) = InputSheet.Cells(FindRowNumber + (TotalCases + 3) * i, x)
                x = x + 1
            Next j
        Next i
    End With



    Background.Range("AC2:AH" & NodeList + 1).Offset(0, c * 7) = LoadCases

    For i = 1 To NodeList * 6 * TotalCases
        With SummaryResults
            If Trim(Cells(i, 5).Value) = intValueToFind Then
                Set FindRow = SummaryResults.Range("A:A").Find(What:=intValueToFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
                SecondRowNumber = FindRow.Row
                GoTo Step2
            End If
        End With
    Next i
Step2:
    With SummaryResults
        For x = 0 To NodeList - 1
            For j = 0 To 5
                SummaryResults.Cells(SecondRowNumber + 1 + j + 6 * x, 5) = Background.Cells(x + 2, 29 + j)
                SummaryResults.Cells(SecondRowNumber + 1 + j + 6 * x, 3) = TypHeader(1)
                SummaryResults.Cells(SecondRowNumber + 1 + j + 6 * x, 4) = LoadDirections(j)
                SummaryResults.Cells(SecondRowNumber + 1 + j + 6 * x, 2) = Nodes(x)
            Next j
        Next x
    End With

Next c





End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. EDIT: Uploaded the entire code. Additional information, the code works when not tabbed into excel but will fail when tabbed in a ran again.

Comment: switch `Set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook` to `Set myBook = Excel.ThisWorkbook`. Also. trap the case when there is no Find, by `If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Also, what is Range("C12:C" & 100) ?

Comment: in `For c = 0 To y` ........ what is ***y*** ?

Comment: Changed to ThisWorkbook, error is still occurring. Is trapping the Find when nothing is found just a troubleshooting step or does something mess up in the code with that being present? Range("C12:C" & 100) refers to the section of column I want the Find to look through. y is the number of iterations I want the code to run through.

Comment: Small comment - what sheet do you expect to Trim the cells on? It's not given in the code. `Trim(Cells(i, 3).Value)` ...should that be `Trim(SummaryResults.Cells(i,3).Value)` for example? Also, when do you declare `TotalCases`? Are you showing the whole code? (I'd also note to add `Option Explicit` at the *very top* before all other code, so you're forced to declare any variables used).

Comment: Placing Option Explicit fixed my problem. I never defined Background as a worksheet. As for the Trim, the statement is within a With block for the sheet I want referenced and that seems to be working. Thanks for the Option Explicit tip, found a couple other variables that were not defined.

Comment: Scratch that, the code ran once and then gave me the same error when I tried to run it again.

Comment: @SgtYui Try setting all .find(arguments) explicitly. Also, do you have any hidden rows in the searched sheets? Off topic: Consider splitting the code to multiple functions, subs, with one goal. Feed output from one as input for another.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the LoadCaseList() array is never getting populated.  This is your Find statement:

```
Set FindRow = InputSheet.Range("C:C").Find(What:=intValueToFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

intValueToFind is set by this statement:

```
intValueToFind = LoadCaseList(c)
```

But the LoadCaseList() array is populated by the following code which is a label that is never called by a GoTo statement (as far as I can tell):

```
LoadCaseList:
For x = 0 To y
    LoadCaseList(x) = Background.Cells(2 + x, 3).text
Next x
```

So because the LoadCaseList label statement is never being called by a GoTo statement, the LoadCaseList() array is never being populated so intValueToFind has no value and therefore the Find method has no value to search for (except for maybe the empty string).